# Можно ли добавить в раздел "Кисть" новый цвет?

Tags: c#, wpf

Можно ли в раздел: "Кисть" добавить ещё какой-то цвет, допустим, о той же мышки, а именно, чтобы можно было менять динамично цвет кнопки, когда к примеру на неё навелся пользователь. Ибо в Winforms при создании своего контрола работает там всё отлично, а в WPF я даже не в курсе, можно ли так сделать...
Или допустим вывести в WPF этот цвет в раздел "Разное", как это сделанно в Winforms, там раздел: "Прочее"

Код для примера:

```
                    <Setter Property="Button.Effect">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DropShadowEffect Color="White" Direction="320" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="7" Opacity="0.6" />
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
```

Допустим чтобы менять цвет: "White" из раздела: Разное

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Ну есть какие-то примеры кода?

Comment: Какой код вы ждете то? Почитайте что такое XAML ресурсы, поймите как они работают, заведите там цвета нужные и используйте, все.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я спросил, можно ли сделать так-же как это было в Winforms, вместо этого вы мне говорите о ресурсах, приведите пример, какие я должен завести нужные цвета, и как их использовать, ничего не понятно.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Зачем вы тогда здесь нужен? Если бы я не просил помощи, я бы не писал, мне стало интересно, решил спросить у людей, ведь этот форум для таких как я, чтобы спросить узнать и т.д, а такой как Вы, и вам подобные не место сдесь.

Comment: По поводу `Или допустим вывести в WPF этот цвет в раздел "Разное", как это сделанно в Winforms, там раздел` - это [DependencyProperty](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/13.3.php), которые создаются у `UserControl`. Создайте простой `UserControl`, пропишите в его cs коде `propdp` и нажмите TAB, вам студия сгенерирует это свойство, остается только задать нужный тип и название. Вот такие свойства студия и отобразит в окне сбоку.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот и совет наконец-то подьехал умный, вместо того, чтобы выделываться кто умнее, кто глупее.

Comment: Какой вопрос, такая и реакция. Он звучит у вас как "Можно ли в раздел: "Кисть" добавить ещё какой-то цвет" - я вам сказал, ресурсы, вы же начали требовать от меня решение, даже не попробовав сами. Вы ожидаете от меня другой реакции?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я прошу показать, Вы же скидывали тему, её реализации, этого было-бы вполне достаточно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так добавляете цвета в **App.xaml**

(кусок разметки из моего проекта, поэтому оставил названия ключей как есть)

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeBackgroundColorKey" Color="#0b344d" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeBackgroundLightColorKey" Color="#0fffffff" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeForegroundColorKey" Color="White" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeTextForegroundColorKey" Color="#cccccc" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeParamForegroundColorKey" Color="#99cc99" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ThemeRedForegroundColorKey" Color="#ff898a" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Использовать вот так

```xml
<TextBox Foreground="{StaticResource ThemeForegroundColorKey}" />
```

В студии отображается вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]